# installing ubuntu in uefi will increase boot speed?

Tags: boot, uefi

i came to know that uefi botting mode gives faster boots. so tell me weather ubuntu supports it ?

if yes then how to install or enable uefi mode in ubuntu ?

i have tried enabling uefi mode from bios but error comes : no bootable media :p!!!

Answer (score 0):

Enabling UEFI in itself does not increase the boot speed. If it does it is marginal.

If you refer to "fast booting" on Windows for the quick reboot: this used to be called hibernation. Ubuntu supports hibernation and when using it starting the system is pretty quick in starting.

If you want to enable UEFI see our [official document](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI). It should answer all the basic questions you might have.

Comment: will you pls tell me how to enable hibernation in ubuntu ?

Comment: @MaulikGangani no? I pick it as an option on my machine when I want to stop it. No enabling required...